# Which Search and Comparison Options should I use to search Chinese characters?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, string-comparison

```
enum {
    NSCaseInsensitiveSearch = 1,
    NSLiteralSearch = 2,
    NSBackwardsSearch = 4,
    NSAnchoredSearch = 8,
    NSNumericSearch = 64,
    NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch = 128,
    NSWidthInsensitiveSearch = 256,
    NSForcedOrderingSearch = 512,
    NSRegularExpressionSearch = 1024
};

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    [self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects];
    for (Notice *notice in allNoticeArray)
    {   
        if ([scope isEqualToString:@"标题"]) 
        {
            NSComparisonResult result = [notice.title compare:searchText
                                                      options:NSWidthInsensitiveSearch
                                                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
            if (result == NSOrderedSame)
            {
                [self.filteredListContent addObject:notice];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `searchText` & `notice.title` are all Chinese characters.

So, which Search and Comparison Options should I use?

Thank you in advance. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `NSWidthInsensitiveSearch` is good to use in your scenario. (Which only needs to check whether the title begins with the keyword, right?)

There is no such consepts as case and diacritic marks in Chinese characters. If you don't have extra requirements like `NSBackwardsSearch` or others, `NSWidthInsensitiveSearch` is fine since you can ignore the difference between full-width and half-width forms of western characters:

> *NSWidthInsensitiveSearch*
>
> Search ignores width differences in characters that have full-width and half-width forms, as occurs in East Asian character sets.
>
> For example, with this option, the full-width Latin small letter 'a' (Unicode code point U+FF41) is equal to the basic Latin small letter 'a' (Unicode code point U+0061).